# PHP IMAP connecting to server TIMEOUT

Tags: php, email, timeout, client, imap

I'm coding very simple email client app with PHP. On my local dev server everything works just fine, but when I move the very same script on production server I get the "Can't connect to secure.emailsrvr.com,993: Connection timed out" response. I tried almost everything, searching the google for two days, but no solution found!

Both servers have the exact configuration, so there is no issues with that! phpinfo() is exactly the same (imap enabled, ssl, ... all extensions are included, server log has no errors)

The username, password and server data is the same and 100% correct (if I change the credentials or server data I get correct error and not timeout). The server support guys assured me the the IP is not blocked.

very simple connect script that I use (here is where it get stucked). Port is correct, also host!

```
$mbox=imap_open("{imap.emailsrvr.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "my_user", "my_pass");
```

Anyone had similar issues?

Regards,
 Jernej Gololicic

Comment: which server support guys? the imap server or the production web server?

Answer (score 0):

If your OSes are different than it's most probably that you have different IMAP extensions installed as well.

Check this out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imap.requirements.php